# Using Postgres param in a function

Tags: postgresql, functions, timestamp

I'm trying to create a few functions to make the SQL queries between my SQLite and Postgres DB's the same.

One thing I would like to do is change a timestamp to a double via a function such as:

```
create function tz_to_double(a timestamp) returns DOUBLE PRECISION as $$
    SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP a);
$$ language sql;
```

Postgres however doesn't allow me to create this function. It errors out like so:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "a"
LINE 2:  SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP a);
```

Would it be possible to create this function / use this as a param?

Comment: Unless you really need the fractional part of the seconds, I would make the return type an [INTEGER](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9bc7f44868f451b4d283f17122e30d76)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding both `Timestamp` and `a` in extract function, just remove `TIMESTAMP`

```
create function tz_to_double(a timestamp) returns DOUBLE PRECISION as $$
    SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM  a);
$$ language sql;
```